# Regular Expression to match specific JSON structure from a log stream; One non capturing group may or may not exist

Tags: arrays, json, regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have a JSON structure like (lets call it a **service** object with 1 or more service_items) :

```
{
  "service_charge": 7500,
  "person_id": 2,
  "service_items": [{
    "line_number": 1,
    "date_of_service": "2018-02-12",
    "provider_id": "YYYYYYY",
    "item_code": "XXXX",
    "service_type": "BBBBBBB",
    "provider_type": "CCCCCCCCC",
    "service_count": 5,
    "validation": {
      "third_party": {
        "rebates": 2200,
        "item_response": "pass"
      },
      "personal": {
        "rebates": null,
        "item_response": "fail"
      }
    }
  },{
    "line_number": 2,
    "date_of_service": "2018-02-12",
    "provider_id": "YYYYYYY",
    "item_code": "XXXX",
    "service_type": "Ancillary",
    "provider_type": "CCCCCCCCC",
    "service_count": 1,
    "validation": {
      "third_party": {
        "rebates": 2200,
        "item_response": "pass"
      },
      "personal": {
        "rebates": null,
        "item_response": "fail",
        "personal_log": [
          {
            "decision_type": "business_rule_x",
            "decision": "not allowed",
            "outcome": "fail",
            "rule_id": "12345",
            "narrative": "not allowed"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to capture individual **service_item** objects from it using the following regular expression:

```
(?<service_item>\{[^{}]+(?:\{[^{}]*(?:\{[^{}]*(?:\{[^{}]*\}[^{}]*)*\}[^{}]*)*[^{}]*\}[^{}]*)*\})
```

The problem:
The **personal_log** array (can be seen in second service item object) is optional and may or may not exist. The regular expression works fine if there is atleast one personal_log present and captures individual service_ietms; but if there is no personal_log present in any of the service_items (shown in JSON below) then it takes the whole service object as one match.

```
{
  "service_charge": 7500,
  "person_id": 2,
  "service_items": [{
    "line_number": 1,
    "date_of_service": "2018-02-12",
    "provider_id": "YYYYYYY",
    "item_code": "XXXX",
    "service_type": "BBBBBBB",
    "provider_type": "CCCCCCCCC",
    "service_count": 5,
    "validation": {
      "third_party": {
        "rebates": 2200,
        "item_response": "pass"
      },
      "personal": {
        "rebates": null,
        "item_response": "fail"
      }
    }
  },{
    "line_number": 2,
    "date_of_service": "2018-02-12",
    "provider_id": "YYYYYYY",
    "item_code": "XXXX",
    "service_type": "Ancillary",
    "provider_type": "CCCCCCCCC",
    "service_count": 1,
    "validation": {
      "third_party": {
        "rebates": 2200,
        "item_response": "pass"
      },
      "personal": {
        "rebates": null,
        "item_response": "fail"
      }
    }
  }
  ]
}
```

I want to capture service_items irrespective of whether the personal_log json array exists or not; I know its something to do with the inner most non-capturing group but I am currently unable to resolve it.

Note: the attributes may appear in any order in the log stream;

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Why not using a json parser?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add first attribute **"line_number"** to be an anchor of your regular expression:

```
(?<service_item>\{[^{}]+"line_number":[^{}]+(?:\{[^{}]*(?:\{[^{}]*(?:\{[^{}]*\}[^{}]*)*\}[^{}]*)*[^{}]*\}[^{}]*)*\})
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work; try with the second JSON structure above on 
https://regex101.com

Comment: I've tried and there are 2 matches, please check  https://regex101.com/r/CMpXrM/1

Comment: @HamzaShahid trying to query json data with regex is generaly not relevant. You may face some problems with nesting depth of braces, and it's highly probable such method won't remain consistent over time.  I strongly suggest you to use a parser.

Comment: @TrungDuong : this seemed to work fine if the first attribute of JSON is line_number which is what I give when putting it in the log stream but it eventually came out that the order changes in the stream and we can have line_number attribute after the inner JSON object (basically the service_item attributes can be in any order in the log stream), how can we update the expression to capture that ?
Example here : https://regex101.com/r/JLp6JX/1

Answer (score 0):

A parser would be the right choice but if your regex engine supports it, you could use recursion to match braces

```
\[[^\[\]]*+(?:(?R)[^\[\]]*+)*+\]
```

[regex101 testcase](https://regex101.com/r/CMpXrM/2)

Comment: Thank you :), this is a good idea too, I was trying capture individual objects and this captures the entire service_items array.